# what will be output of the following code and why ? can anyone explain?

Tags: c, increment

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 6;
    printf("%d %d", ++i, i++);//printing
    return 0;
}
```

What will be output of the following code and why?

Comment: NO.   It's UB. Please go away and tell your prof/TA NOT to issue such homework in the future:(

Comment: If it's not UB, it's USB.  Either way, it's madcademic.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("%d %d",++i ,i++);//printing
```

Is undefined behavior.  The order of argument processing is not specifically defined in the C standard, it is not possible to predict exactly what the output will be. It could be anything at all according to *[this](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)*.